# Socat - Virtual serial network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-port

I've to simulate 3 different application, each of wich is connected to a different serial modem(rs232).
I want that each application talks with the others by writing on a "virtual" serial line
I tried to configure the `socat` application but now i've the communication between only two clients by using this command:

```
socat pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

Do you know how to create a pseudo-network of virtual serial port for simulating the behavior of different number of modem clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socat can be used for creating a network o serial port by using a ip socket as a "broker".
This is the command that can be used for each port that we want to create:

`sudo socat ip:localhost:222 pty,raw,echo=0`